# consuming message from a queue through spring integration

Tags: java, jms, spring-integration

I have the below configuration in which it connects to a queue that is basically a tibco queue and drops a message into the queue now i want to enhance it to the receiver part also

I want to create a separate xml configuration in which the jms adapter will connect to tibco message broker and consume message from a that same queue and write that message on a text file and stored that text file in my C drive , please advise how that configuration would be

for the sender part i have the following configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">     

<context:component-scan base-package="com.apress.prospringintegration" /> 

 <int:poller  id="poller" default="true" >
 <int:interval-trigger interval="200"/>
 </int:poller> 



<int:channel id="input">
<int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>

<bean id="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
<property name="environment">
<props>
<prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</prop>
<prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://werems1.fm.absgrp.net:5678</prop>
<prop key="java.naming.security.principal">xyz</prop>
<prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">xyz</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSConnFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>GenericConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

 <bean id="tibcosendJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref local="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDestinationName">
            <value>qwert.dev.queue.test.data</value>
        </property>         
        <property name="pubSubDomain">
            <value>false</value> 
        </property>
        <property name ="receiveTimeout">
            <value>120000</value>
        </property> 
    </bean>    

   <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="input" destination-name="qwert.dev.queue.test.data"  connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" /> 



</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

`int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter -> int-file:outbound-channel-adapter`

On the sender side, your `input` channel need not be a queue channel; remove the queue element; similarly on the receiver side, just use a direct channel.

**EDIT**:

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
        destination-name="qwert.dev.queue.test.data"
        channel="jmsInChannel" />

<channel id="jmsInChannel" />

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="jmsInChannel" directory="/tmp"
  filename-generator-expression=
   "new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS').format(new java.util.Date()) + '.txt'" />
```

**EDIT2**

Expression is not available before Spring Integration 3.0.x...

```
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="jmsInChannel" directory="/tmp"
        filename-generator="generator" />

<bean id="generator" class="foo.TimestampTextGenerator" />
```

and

```
public class TimestampTextGenerator implements FileNameGenerator {

    @Override
    public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
        return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS")
                .format(new java.util.Date()) + ".txt";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , just to add please request you to show a bit how can i recieve the message from queue and write each message to an individual file , Thanks in advance that will help me to grasp a lot and the filename would be as per the time stamp when the message is completely written in file so the name of the file would be message-timestamp.txt

Comment: getting this below error  Cannot resolve reference to bean 'new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS').format(new java.util.Date()) + '.txt'' while setting bean property 'fileNameGenerator'

Comment: the problem is that i want to consume the messages from queue and write them to a text file but the name of the text file would be of timestamp.txt such that name itself suggests when the file is been created

Comment: That's **exactly** what this sample does; it appears you are setting `filename-generator` (which references a bean) instead of `filename-generator-expression` (which uses a SpEL expression to generate the file name). If `filename-generator-expression` is not available, you must be using a **very** old version of the framework. The current version is 4.2.5.RELEASE. Please [read the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-writing).

Comment: I am currently using spring integration version 2-0-5 mote bhi that mite be the reason

Comment: Will go for latest one,  please advise which is the latest version of spring integration jars version

Comment: See 3 comments up - 4.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: Thanks a lot will go for these jars also please advise do such jars have any such a dependency if I still use jdk 1.5 version

Comment: Yikes! No; java 6 is the minimum; if you have to use such an old java and SI, you can't use an expression for the filename. The expression was introduced in version 3 which needs java 6. You will need to write a java class that implements `FileNameGenerator` to generate the file name and use the `filename-generator` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Gary hope u know understand my problem can you please show a little how a class will implement a file generator and how I will use the attribute filenames generator please advise as I have to use jdk1.5

Comment: You have to do your own investigation - I can't keep writing your code for you; if you read the documentation as I suggested, it will be clear. I have edited my answer one more time, but I can't keep doing this for you.